# Changing locale in angular-translate filter without globally changing the language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

My use case is a list of keys and translated values, a definition list like:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Translation Key</dt>
  <dd>{{category.key}}</dd>
  <dt>English Translation</dt>
  <dd>{{category.key | translate }}</dd>
  <dt>German Translation</dt>
  <dd>{{category.key | translate }}</dd>
</dl>
```

The current solution will obviously translate into the currently preferred language, not both.

Is there a way to tell the `translate` filter to use a specific language just for that key? The [documentation](http://angular-translate.github.io/angular-translate/docs/en/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.filter%3atranslate) references an interpolation hash, but I have not yet found something that would help me with passing a specific language to the filter. I am using version 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

No this is currently not possible, but there's a request for a `$translate.override()` method which could be used for that.